# Integration Tests with Gradle 5.0

Tags: java, testing, gradle, task, integration-testing

I'd like to create dedicated task for integration test in gradle. 
I have multimodule project. In project build.gradle I've task:

```
integrationTest(type:Test){
    useJUnit {
        includeCategories("examplePackage.IntegrationTest")
    }
}
```

It should run tests marked with:
@Category(IntegrationTest.class)

but when I run this, it says **Test events were not received**.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

JUnit Platform introduced [tagging](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-tagging-and-filtering) to replace categories.

Gradle adopted to this. See [user guide test grouping](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/java_testing.html#test_grouping)